# IOS Core Data Concurrency

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

We are developing an IPad application with synchronization support, this synchronization logic is launched at the startup of the application to check if there are any updates by invoking a WCF service.

As the synchronization process takes time, we would like to put it on a background worker to not block the user interface, so my question is:

- is it possible to develop a background worker that synchronize the sqlite database on background and on the same time the user interface is using this database? If it's possible can you please provide code or links to help me implement this?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible. What you are referring to is Threading where a process is done in the Background. Read up on Apple's [Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/) and [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get a better idea on how exactly it's implemented in iOS

Comment: +1 Background processing of a server connection is a very common requirement.